# MongoDB Shell SyntaxError: unexpected token: string literal

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I’m trying to connect to the sandbox for the MongoDB University into course, but keep getting syntax errors when I use the copied command from Atlas to connect.

MongoDB Shell version 4.2.3
What can I do about this problem?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/6678) solve your problem?

Comment: Nope, it didn't.

Comment: You are already connected. As can be seen at the start of the line `MongoDB Enterprise >`

Answer (score 1):

The stuff you typed (which you should provide as text, not as image) is what you would type in a Linux shell like bash. When you type that you get the `mongo` shell opened (the `MongoDB Enterprise >` prompt). In the `mongo` shell prompt, you'd type whatever the next step of the tutorial is.